# read input from console without node.js

Tags: javascript

Hey I was wondering if there's a js equivalent to `cin` from c++. I tried using `readLine()` and `prompt` as suggested on the internet but I have been thrown `Undefined Reference` for both functions. Later I found out that readLine and prompt both run on Node.js or smth but I was wondering if there's a command I can use to run smth that's just pure HelloWorld.js and stuff.

(I haven't learned Node.js so correct me if I'm misunderstanding this)

Thanks.

Here's some of my code if it helps at all:

```
theInput = readline();
```

I have tried:

```
const readLine = require('readline');

const theInput = readline.createInterface({
          input: process.stdin,
          output: process.stdout
});
```

and

```
const theInput = prompt("What's your name?");
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without nodejs"?  Are you running this code in a browser?  Something else?

Comment: Are you trying to insert some values through browser console?

Comment: @LazarNikolic Yes :) through onecompiler

Comment: @David I'm running my code on onecompiler and I want to be able to use the console to do stuff. I don't have Node.js or anything it's just a .js file

Comment: @charlotte: In that case it's *probably* using NodeJS under the hood.  Using the `readLine` package is the way to go.  However, the code you're showing has a typo.  `readLine` is not the same as `readline`, casing matters.  The line beginning with `const theInput = ...` needs to reference the variable `readLine`.